# How to fetch the data from WebServices by Get Method and want to save into MutableDictionary in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios4

How to fetch the data from Web Services by Get Method and want to save into Mutable Dictionary in iPhone.....thnx

Comment: in which format is your response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using JSOn webservice to get the data then try out this tutorial

```
#import 

@interface jsonViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    NSMutableData *responseData;
}


Replace the contents of jsonViewController.m with:


#import "jsonViewController.h"
#import "JSON/JSON.h"

@implementation jsonViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yourwebservice.com"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [responseData release];

    NSArray *tempArray = [responseString JSONValue];
}
```

Comment: [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

have i use to set the delegate methods or not....

OR

responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

i use ARC in MyProject so it wont have retain...so what i have to write  on that....

Comment: you have to use delegate method for getting data

Comment: @Pravi - instead of creating an instance variable, use property which will help you to manage responseData even in ARC.